# Shinyapps.io and incorrect rendering of missing values

Tags: r, missing-data, shinyapps

I have a flexdashboard with shiny components that I've published to shinyapps.io

When I run the document locally, missing values in the tables appear as "—" (see below).

[image]

However, when I publish the document to shinyapp.io, the missing values appear as "<97>" (see below).

[image]

I have tried specifying the missing values as NA with `na_if()` but I get the same outcome and I have also tried specifying "—" as `na.strings` when I created the table:

`data <- read.table(text = readLines("file.csv", warn = FALSE), header = TRUE,sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "—")`

Is there any way to specify how missing values should be rendered upon publishing of a .rmd file? What trick am I missing?